# Relationship between graph walks and spectral radius

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spectral-radius

I want to explore what's the relationship between graph walks and spectral radius. I read this result in a paper, however, I could not either find the material that the paper cite on the internet or prove it myself. Could someone help me with how to prove this result?

$$\exp\left(h(G)\right)=\rho(G)$$

where $h(G)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{1}{n}\ln\left(\#V^{n}\right)}$, $\#V^{n}$ represents the number of $n$-walks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Looking up "Gelfand's formula" on Wikipedia might help you.